# How do I write & in a formula within quotation marks?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im currently figuring out how to write "&" in a formula so that VBA recognizes it as a string and not as the &-operator.

My formula looks like this:

```
"=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">""&0.5*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
```

But it should look something like this, as I want to use the variable z instead of 0.5

```
"=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" & Chr(34)& Chr(38) & Chr(34)& z & *MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
```

As you see I already tried to write the "" and the & as ASCII but it seems that even this doenst work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: The result should look like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C31:C6413;">"&0.5*MAX(C31:C6413))
```

EDIT: will post another question with the whole code. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437734/i-want-to-replace-a-number-with-a-variable-that-is-linked-with-a-cell-input-but)

Comment: Try this:  "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">""&" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"

Comment: Still error '1004'

Comment: Notice the syntax highlighting (it's probably much less obvious in the VBE with the standard highlighting): `& Total &` is being evaluated as a variable by VBA (if it's undeclared and you have `Option Explicit` the code doesn't compile?); if you want `& Total &` to be evaluated by the Excel calculation engine rather than VBA, you need to double up (/escape) these quotes: `"=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R["" & Total & ""]C[-4],"">""&0.5*MAX(RC[-4]:R["" & Total & ""]C[-4]))"`, and now `Total` is expected to be resolvable by Excel (a named range?).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but i want & Total & to be registered as a variable. That is working out perfect as written in the first code window. I only want to replace the 0.5 in the formula with an variable that is set as a double called z. Therefore I also need an "&" in the formula, but VBA recognizes the "&" as an operator.

Comment: You're missing double quotes then

Comment: Does the original formula work?

Comment: Yes the original formula

"=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">""&0.5*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"

works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `Chr(34)` for `"` and `Chr(38)` for `&`, they're unnecessary indirection making the code harder to reason about. `&` doesn't need escaping, and to have a `"` literal inside a string you escape it by doubling it up, so `""""` is a string containing a single `"` character.

Concatenating long strings with escaped double-quotes can be a frustrating experience... what if we broke down the steps, and added a bit of space around operators?

The cognitive load is immediately reduced, and any error in the logic is much easier to spot:

```
Dim avgSourceRangePart As String
avgSourceRangePart = "RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]"

Dim maxPart As String
maxPart = "MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4])"

Dim avgConditionPart As String
avgConditionPart = """>"" & " & z & " * " & maxPart & ")"
```

Now the final concatenation looks like this:

```
"=AVERAGEIF(" & avgSourceRangePart & "; " & avgConditionPart ")"
```

Comment: @Proliner not in this code. You have not showed anyone where `Total` and `z` are coming from. If they're coming from a cell value, then they can be `Variant/Error`, and you can't implicitly convert such a value into a string (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: oh sorry sure;
Dim z As Double
z = Worksheets(1).Range("O1").Value
Dim Total as Long
Total= wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Comment: Looks like `z` isn't needed and should appear as `Sheet1!O1` in the generated formula. Still, *which instruction* is throwing the type mismatch? If a `Variant/Error` is involved, that would be at `z = Worksheets(1).Range("O1").Value`, or at `Total = ...` if the `Count` yields an error value.

Comment: @Proliner just noticed your other comment "The cell value is #DIV/0 because my worksheet is blank" -- that's your type mismatch right there. You can't store a division by zero error into a `Long`, make that a `Variant`, and bail out (`Exit Sub`, or `Exit Function`, depending) when `IsError(Total)` is true.

Comment: It says there is an error with avgConditionPart: Compiling error

Comment: @Proliner I missed the closing parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: the other comment with the blank sheet was submitted by Toddleson, not by me.

Comment: @Proliner perhaps, but the only way this code can throw a type mismatch error is if one of the variables involves a `Variant/Error`; your code should already handle that well before it attempts to consume this value.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your patience and help. Unfortunately it tells me "Application-defined or object-defined error" within here : .Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(" & avgSourceRangePart & ";" & avgConditionPart & ")"

Comment: @Proliner `.Formula` wants A1-style notation, you're using R1C1. Have you tried using `.FormulaR1C1` instead? (side note, *consider* using A1-style notation instead, it works nicely with `.Cells`)

Comment: Another side note, @Proliner that's yet another good reason to *include ALL the relevant code in your original post* ;-)

Comment: @Proliner try `Debug.Print "=AVERAGEIF(" & avgSourceRangePart & "; " & avgConditionPart ")"` then grab the output from the debug pane (Ctrl+G), copy it and then paste it into the cell you mean to have it in: Excel should give you a more meaningful error message, and then you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: opened up another question with the full code as this post here is kinda full with comments^^

Comment: @Proliner I think the problem is the `;` semicolon separator. It wasn't clear whether your list separator character was a comma or a semicolon.... your question includes both. Change the `;` for a `,` if that's what your workstation uses: it's controlled by Windows regional settings.

Comment: even with the , instead of ; same error. And the debug.print doesnt do anything. (maybe im using it wrong)

Comment: @Proliner `Debug.Print` outputs to the debug pane so you can grab the fully evaluated resulting string from the debugger output. Ctrl+G to bring up the *Immediate* toolwindow that will show this output. And... that's your new best friend right there ;-)

Comment: actually just hovered over the line with the error and all the variables "avgSourceRangePart" and "avgConditionPart" show the perfect formula. It even shows 0.5 that is saved in the z. Still the error. Strg+G doesnt show me anything in the tab. Thanks for the tips Mathieu :)

Comment: Just found the answer/problem: As im using german as an office language we usually write double figures as 0,5. VBA wants to get the double as 0.5 in the formula which leads then to an error.. So have to figure out how to change my z value in between from "," to "."
Anyway i will upvote both of your answers after i got enough reputation. Thank you for all your patience and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

```vb
"=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
```

Comment: .Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"

still gives me the same error :(

Comment: I get no errors when I do `Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"` . The cell value is `#DIV/0` because my worksheet is blank, but when I add numbers, it works as intended.

Comment: The only way I could see there being an error is if `Total` is an invalid input, if `z` is not numeric or `.Cells` is not inside a `With`

Comment: z is a double and Total as Long.
Error message 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: What about `.Cells`, is there a valid Range reference in the `With` statement?

Comment: wb as Workbook set to this Workbook;

With wb.Worksheet(1)
.Cells(....
End With

Comment: Paste the code as a new question and I'll take a look.

Comment: just did that, Link is pasted in this question

Comment: Thank you. Since @Mathieu Guindon and I have both provided correct answers in this post, please give one of us the check mark and an upvote.

Comment: They are both still not working tbh... I wish this would be correct

Comment: dont have enough reputation for that