# I want to replace a number with a variable that is linked with a Cell input, but i get an error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I already posted the question with only particles of my code. I want to replace the 0.5 in the following formula with my double variable z.

```
.Cells(21, 6).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">""&0.5*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
```

My whole code looks like this:

```
Sub ImportMultipleTextFile()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim InputTextFile As Variant
Dim SourceDataFolder As String
Dim OutputDataFolder As String
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim Total As Long
x = 3
Dim Dateiname As String
Dim z As Double
z = Worksheets(1).Range("O1").Value

If MsgBox("Kistler Drehdaten?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Wähle den Kistler Ordner aus mit den .txt Dateien"


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.Clear
    End With
                                                        
SourceDataFolder = MyFolder



'Loop through each text file in source folder
InputTextFile = Dir(SourceDataFolder & "\*.txt")
While InputTextFile <> ""
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=SourceDataFolder & "\" & InputTextFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True


Dateiname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Range("A:E").Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:E").PasteSpecial
Total = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Dim avgSourceRangePart As String
avgSourceRangePart = "RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]"
Dim maxPart As String
maxPart = "MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4])"
Dim avgConditionPart As String
avgConditionPart = """>"" & " & z & " * " & maxPart & ")"


With wb.Worksheets(1)
.Cells(21, 6).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">""&0.5*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
'.Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
'.Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
.Cells(21, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(" & avgSourceRangePart & ";" & avgConditionPart & ")"
.Cells(21, 8).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">""&0.5*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
.Range("F21:H21").Copy
End With

    x = x + 1
Range("A:I").Clear
'Close the opened input file
Workbooks(InputTextFile).Close
InputTextFile = Dir

Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
End Sub
```

....followed by another elseif with the same style for different text packages that need to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67436790/14608750) -
The line you're looking for is:

```vb
"=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
```

But there are other problems with the code that cause errors.

The main problem was with `Range("A:E").Copy`. The range was not qualified, meaning it was referring to the wrong book. See the corrected code below:

```vb
Sub ImportMultipleTextFile()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim InputTextFile As Variant
    Dim SourceDataFolder As String
    Dim OutputDataFolder As String
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim x As Integer:    x = 3
    Dim Total As Long
    Dim TxtFile As Workbook
    Dim z As Double
    
    z = Worksheets(1).Range("O1").Value
    
    If MsgBox("Kistler Drehdaten?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Wähle den Kistler Ordner aus mit den .txt Dateien"
    
    
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
               .AllowMultiSelect = False
               .Show
               MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
               Err.Clear
        End With
                                                                
        SourceDataFolder = MyFolder
        
        
        
        'Loop through each text file in source folder
        InputTextFile = Dir(SourceDataFolder & "\*.txt")
        While InputTextFile <> ""
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=SourceDataFolder & "\" & InputTextFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
            Set TxtFile = Application.Workbooks(InputTextFile)
            
            TxtFile.Sheets(1).Range("A:E").Copy
            wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:E").PasteSpecial
            Total = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
            
            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                .Cells(21, 6).Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"
                .Range("F21:H21").Copy
            End With
            
            Range("A:I").Clear
            'Close the opened input file
            TxtFile.Close
            InputTextFile = Dir
        
        Wend
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. it actually did work before but I guess to define the txtworkbook before makes sense. Unfortunately I still get the error "Application-defined or object-defined error" for the formula line that you posted.

Comment: Even with FormulaR1C1 i get the same error message.. :(
.Cells(21, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4],"">"" &" & z & "*MAX(RC[-4]:R[" & Total & "]C[-4]))"

Comment: @Proliner My guess would be that pasting the R1C1 offsets (more specifically, column index -4) in column A is attempting to refer to a negative column which doesn't exist, hence the error. Avoid R1C1 everywhere you can, use A1 notation and refer to explicit columns instead of offsets.

Comment: but the exact same formula without the z does work. so this should not be the error or am i missing something?